# can't find FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, parse-platform

I'm a android developer and i'm new to Xcode and objective-c.

I'm using parse.com in my app and I'm trying to add the ability to login with face however, one of the headers of `ParseFacebookUtils` framework need the header `FacebookSDK` which is no more included in the new Facebook SDK.

Further investigation showed me that i need the FBSession header but i couldn't find it either.

Is there a solution for this? I'm using the newest Xcode, parse sdks and Facebook sdks.

EDIT:

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"user_about_me", @"user_friends", @"email"] block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Im here anyway!");
        if (!user) {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
        } else if (user.isNew) {
            NSLog(@"User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"User logged in through Facebook!");
        }
    }];
```

EDIT2:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  Listo
//
//  Created by Amit Baz on 5/12/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Amit Baz. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [FBSDKLoginButton class];

    [Parse setApplicationId:@""
                  clientKey:@""];

    [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:launchOptions];

    [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse supports both v4.x and v3.x of the Facebook SDK. If you're using v4.x of the Facebook SDK, then instead of importing `ParseFacebookUtils`, you'll need to:

```
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>
```

See https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#fbusers for more info.

Comment: Thank you kind sir! that works! However, when i try to connect via Facebook with the message that is in the post(edited), There  is no log written to the console which means the message doesn't "work", can u help me with that?

Comment: What happens when you call that method? Does it switch over to the Facebook app or to Safari? Do you have fb{app_id} listed as a scheme in your plist?

Comment: It switches to the safari cause i don't have the fb app in the simulator and i do have fb{app_id} listed as a scheme inside URL types

Comment: In that case, when you finish login, does it open your app? And if so, are you calling the `FBSDKApplicationDelegate`'s `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` method from your AppDelegate?

Comment: I do have this method but i don't call her

Comment: Yeah, please follow the docs I posted in the answer. You need to call both `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` from your AppDelegate.

Comment: I added my appDelagate to the post, can u please tell me what's missing? i followed the docs and couldn't find an instructions abut this functions

Comment: That should be good enough. Although you should probably edit your post so your parse app ID and client key isn't publicly exposed on the internets.

Comment: so why the slog comments doesn't appear on the console?

Comment: I don't know. At this point, you should probably ask in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Delete FacebookSDK from 
**Build Phases-- > Link Binary With Libraries** Delete FacebookSDK.framework
Add the FacebookSDK framework again

Comment: There is no FacebookSDK.framework anymore...the new sdk contains other frameworks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Facebook SDK had a major update in v4.0 that split it up into multiple frameworks.  Until parse is updated to work with the new SDK, you'll have to download and use a v3.x or lower version of the Facebook SDK.

Comment: Where can i find a lower cersion?